# in javascript, how do you determine the type of an dom object, for example, HTMLLIElement or HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, dom, html

with dom elements, how can I get the object type?

the only clue I can see is the `_proto_` method using the same name.  promisingly, it has an inheritance `_proto_` as well.

excepting IE, is this the right path to follow?

if so, what would

```
function getNodeType( node ) return string
// would return HTMLLIElement for example

function isNodeType( node, type ) return boolean
// whether node is or is inherited from that type
```

would look like?

Comment: Maybe you could parse it with Regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
el.tagName;
```

Or, look at the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: tagName will return the name of the tag, eg "li", "html"

Comment: apparently close as can get.  el.nodeName probably a little better.

Comment: I've found that instanceof can get you into trouble x-browser. As such, I would suggest sticking to checking el.nodeName.

Answer (score 4):

`instanceof` should be fine if you are only dealing with one document. If you are testing objects from another frame, then `instanceof` won't work:

```
document.body instanceof HTMLBodyElement  // true
var iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
iframe.contentDocument.body instanceof HTMLBodyElement  // false!
```

Instead, you have to do string comparisons. This is what Google Closure ended up doing to [implement `goog.isArray`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.source.html#line580) (before `Array.isArray([])` was invented). For example:

```
iframe.contentDocument.body.toString() === '[object HTMLBodyElement]'  // true
```

But I would recommend just using `tagName` or `nodeName`.

Comment: the problem with using tagName or nodeName is they are not symmetrical with instanceof  - even <code>document.body instanceof "HTMLElement"</code> fails because "HTMLElement" is quoted, and there's no automatic coercion between strings and object types

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNodeType( node, type ){
    return node instanceof type;
}
function getNodeType(node){
    return node.__proto__;
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
isNodeType(div, HTMLDivElement);   // true
getNodeType(div);                               // HTMLDivElement
```

Comment: return node.__proto__ returns a newly created node of that type, is that not correct?  think I'm after the name of the object type, not an instance of the object type.

Comment: @cc young  node.__proto__ return the constructor function of node